# nuspec omit dlls to be referenced from the lib folder

Tags: c#, nuget, nuspec

I have the following nuspec structure:

```
lib
  net40
    mylib.dll
```

And the following nuspec file

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    ...
    <references>
      <!-- don't want to add a reference to mylib.dll. Doesn't work! -->
    </references> 
    ...
  </metadata>

  <files>    
    <file src="bin\Release\**\*" target="lib\net40"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

I tried to make an empty references block, but it still adds a reference to mylib.dll. I really want mylib.dll to be in the lib folder, because resharper finds it with <kbd>ALT + ENTER</kbd>.

How can I omit the reference but still keep the file in my lib folder?

Comment: What's the benefit of *not* having it as a reference?

Comment: There are multiple reasons that rely on each other. I could elaborate on the actual problem, but this is a solution that would help fix my actual problem. I tried to simplify the question.

The actual problem is that I would like it to be on copy-local=false, but not for all consumers. So I cannot add it to the install script. But I do want to have Update-Package working automatically. So I wrote some other install scripts that fix most parts. But copy-local=false for some, but not all projects is not a general solution.

Comment: Another use case would be design-time-only assemblies. You don't want them to be referenced by any regular project, but you want that visual studio finds them in the right folder for every framework version.